# How i Can Create a Volume Div For the Iframe where i can Control the Iframe Volume without click on IFrame Volume icon?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I want to create a separate div down the iframe where I can control the volume of the iframe without clicking on the iframe volume icon

```
Iframe Code is here but it could not run here you can run it in the w3school.com compiler.
```

```html
<div class="entry-content post-body" id="post-body-5924716169213906958">&nbsp;
    <div class="separator" style="clear:both"><iframe frameborder="0" height="500" id="thatframe" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" src="https://www.newucp.com/hembedplayer/webcricn02/3/800/500" width="100%"></iframe></div>
    </div>
```

Frame Source Code is here Because the Code is lengthy and cannot paste here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ml47hstakk177wt/Framea%20Source%20Code.txt?dl=0

Picture of Iframe
[image: Iframe Image]

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: i tried a lot to target the icon but I failed to target it, Actually, I want to remove the set timeout function from it because it contains some ads which really prosthetic and annoying

Comment: @AnanthDev Do you have any idea how to do this work or stop the set timeout event?

Comment: @Akash - How do you suppose people could help you manipulate the html, when all you've done is supply a screen-shot of its rendered appearance?!

Comment: @enhzflep I have already provided the iframe code I hope that's enough for my question as I tried to share the iframe code here but it was out of the limit to send here so i decided the helper will inspect its code themselves

Comment: @enhzflep Please check now my post I have updated, Please help me if possible